# Invalid copilot token: missing token: 403

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, token, github-copilot

I have been using copilot for a long time. Yesterday I changed my github password and started getting this error in copilot: `Invalid copilot token: missing token: 403`  I tried logging in and out and reinstalling the ide but unfortunately I didn't get any results. Thank you if you can help me.

I tried closing and reopening my account and restarting the ide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple reasons this could be happening.

- The most basic thing to check first is that you've actually properly followed all the steps for setting up GitHub Copilot usage. You can find such docs [on VS Code's docs site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github-copilot) and [on GitHub itself](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot?tool=vscode). Those steps include installing [the VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot), authorizing VS Code in GitHub, and activating your free trial / paid subscription.
- If you don't have a GitHub Copilot subscription, then you can sign up for one by following the steps in https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/quickstart#signing-up-for-github-copilot-for-your-personal-account. For personal accounts, TL;DR go to https://github.com/settings/copilot and click "Enable GitHub Copilot", etc.
- It could be due to an error connecting to the GitHub API to request a token for GitHub Copilot usage. You can request another token by signing out and then back in to GitHub Copilot from VS Code. You may or may not need to revoke VS Code's access to your Github from [Authorized Apps](https://github.com/settings/applications) before trying to sign back in to GitHub Copilot in VS Code again.

  [The docs for troubleshooting authentication issues](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-issues-with-github-copilot-chat#troubleshooting-authentication-issues-in-visual-studio-code) say to sign out of your GitHub account *in VS Code*, reload VS Code (using the `Developer: Reload Window` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), and then sign back into your GitHub account in VS Code.
- If you use multiple GitHub accounts in VS Code, you might need to do some sign-in sign-out dances ([source](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/47577#discussioncomment-5581085)).
- It could be due to trade controls (country things / region-based restrictions). See https://docs.github.com/en/site-policy/other-site-policies/github-and-trade-controls for more info.
- It could because of a bug in GitHub Copilot or a deployment mistake. Ex. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/47577#discussioncomment-4998002, https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/47577#discussioncomment-5079299, https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/40019#discussioncomment-4234433, and more examples on https://www.githubstatus.com/history. If it's a non-server-side bug, it might be fixed in the [pre-release channel](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#prerelease-extensions) of the extension, so you could try switching the release channel.
- If you're the kind of person who likes reading things to try to find a solution before asking for help, you could try combing through a google-search of "`site:github.com "Invalid copilot token: missing token: 403"`".
- Someone in the comments here said they got this error because they meant to use a different GitHub account and were using the wrong one.
- If *none* of that works, then you can reach out the support team on [their support page](https://support.github.com/contact). If you end up finding out some info that could potentially help others, please come back here and post an answer post about it.

Comment: I did everything you said, but the problem is still not fixed. There is no source I have not entered on the internet, but I still get the same "Invalid copilot token: missing token: 403 " I get the error thank you.

Comment: @yafeshanünal did you reach out to the support team? because that's what you should do, and what I said to do in my answer post if nothing else I wrote works.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I have reported the problem to the github support team, if I can make any progress, I will write here.

Comment: This answer is so Chat-GPT-ish that I wonder who's the bot here. I got here because in my case because it was the wrong github account I was using.

Comment: @StarShine I can see why you think that. fyi- I'm one of the primary contributors to enforcement of the AI-generated-content ban on SO. it would be extremely hypocritical of me to have done what you're accusing me of having done. you might want to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390246/997587 (I.e. I did a web search and shared what my research found, which I'm aware LLM+browser technologies do something similar to, and I'm okay with _people_ doing web searches and writing up what they find in a effort to be helpful (with responsibility)) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424111

Comment: It's a great answer and this a great comment, it just shows how difficult the future will become for us humans to distinguish between what's original and what was refurbished from statistics

Comment: I removed account a couple of times and restarted a couple of times. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, after contacting github support, my account was unmarked and activated.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, worked for me when I signed out and signed back in from Visual Studio Code > Accounts.
As previously I signed in for VSCode with my older github account on which copilot was not activated.

[image]

Comment: my answer already mentioned signing out and back in again.